# how to display alert dialog box in button if target action fails

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create an app where the user can take a photo and set it as wallpaper.Now when i click the button and get back without taking a photo and click set wallpaper i want to display an alert dialog box.I have been able to set it when the image capture is not initiated but not when initiated but no image is taken

```
package com.sagarapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Camera extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

ImageView img;
ImageButton takepic;
Button setdp;
Intent i;
final static int cameraData = 0;
Bitmap bmp;
final Context context = this;
boolean taken = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photo);
    initialize();
    takepic.setOnClickListener(this);
    setdp.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Ivpic);
    takepic = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Ibcapture);
    setdp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Bsetdp);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.Ibcapture:
        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        taken = true;
        startActivityForResult(i,cameraData);
        break;
    case R.id.Bsetdp:
        try {
            if(taken)
                getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bmp);
            else{
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBulider = new AlerDialog.Builder(context);
            alertDialogBulider.setTitle("Warning!");
            alertDialogBulider.setMessage("No Image Is Available");
            alertDialogBulider.setCancelable(false);
  alertDialogBulider.setNeutralButton("OK", new   DialogInterface.OnClickListener()   {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBulider.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap)extras.get("data");
        img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
    else
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBulider = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBulider.setTitle("Warning!");
        alertDialogBulider.setMessage("No Photo Is Taken");
        alertDialogBulider.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialogBulider.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBulider.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You mean when the user starts the camera and presses back button?

Comment: If the user presses back button or cancels the picture after capturing it (on the preview screen), the result code in onActivityResult() will be 0 (RESULT_CANCELED). Just check is the resultCode is 0 and show yout AlertDialog

Comment: i mean when the user starts the camera and presses back button and clicks the set wallpaper.when he normally clicks the set wallpaper without initiating the camera the dialog box displays but when the user starts camera and doesn't take photo and clicks the set wallpaper i get error

Comment: OK. That is different. Your taken boolean variable should only be set to true if you receive a RESULT_OK resultcode in onActivityResult. Not inside case R.id.Ibcapture onClick () method.

Comment: Fine. I am going to write an answer. Please accept it/up-vote it if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `taken` `boolean` variable should only be set to true if you receive a `RESULT_OK` resultcode in `onActivityResult()` method. That means that the user actually took a picture and saved it. Remove it from the `R.id.Ibcapture` `View` `onClick ()` method.